# CSS Selector, div input:checked

Tags: html, css

How could I repair it, I needed in checkbox with the div (without div in both parts it works), I can use only pure CSS.

Html:

```
<div><input type="checkbox"></div>
<ul>
    <li>PSD WEBSITES</li>
    <li>UI KITS</li>
    <li>PREMIUM PSD</li>
    <li>ABOUT</li>
    <li>BLOG</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
div input:checked ~ ul {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> The ~ combinator separates two selectors and matches the second
>   element only if it is preceded by the first, and both share a common
>   parent.

You have to change your html structure to:

```css
div input:checked ~ ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <ul>
    <li>PSD WEBSITES</li>
    <li>UI KITS</li>
    <li>PREMIUM PSD</li>
    <li>ABOUT</li>
    <li>BLOG</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Reference**

[General sibling selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)

Comment: I need to use them like 2 elements, role of the first div is a border